# Vagrant creating another VM instead of boot up the default VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I'm using Vagrant on Windows to create my dev environment. But today when I start it with the command `vagrant up`, it created another VM instead of using the one I always used it.

Looking in the folder `C:/Users/My_User/VirtualBox VMs` I found the default VM files.

How to proced to make Vagrant recognize this default VM?

PS: Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: did you set env variable `VAGRANT_CWD` ? this would point to VM in another directory. did vagrant recreate the `id` file with the reference of the new VM ?

Comment: Can you paste your VagrantFile for us please, there could be something in there instructing Vagrant to provision another box.